# Why is the queryset empty when I inject the views to the html?

Tags: python, django, templates, view, frame

Why aren't the posts being published in templates?
I'm trying to create a stock blog page and right now in this project, I'm having problems with the template and the views, the thing is that I want to display the posts that have the same charfield as the url, but I don't understand why it is sending me to the else in the template, which says "sorry, this page does not exists"

urls.py (I will only show the relevant one)

```py
from django.urls import path
from app1 import views
from .views import PostView, ArticleDetailView, AddPostView, UpdatePostView, DeletePostView, AddCategoryView, CategoryView, LikeView, MyPostsView, AddCommentView, UpdateCommentView, DeleteCommentView

app_name = 'app1'

urlpatterns = [
    
    path('stock/<str:sym>/', views.StockView, name = 'stock'),
]
```

views.py

```py
def StockView(request, sym):
    stock_posts = Post.objects.filter(stock__symbol=sym.lower())
    return render(request, 'app1/stockview.html', {'stock':stock_posts})
```

models.py

```py
class StockNames(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.symbol
        
    

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 255)
    header_image = models.ImageField(null = True, blank = True, upload_to = 'images/')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = RichTextField(blank = True, null = True)
    #body = models.TextField()
    post_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='coding')
    snippet = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name = 'blog_posts')
    stock = models.ForeignKey(StockNames, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + ' | ' + str(self.author)
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('app1:article-detail', args=(self.id,))
```

template

```
{% extends "app1/base.html" %}
{% block body_block %}

{{stocks}}

{% endblock %}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: it seems like you have to split this huge task into pieces.. You need to debug carefully.

Comment: Remember that a foreign key contains the id of the  related row. To filter for the symbol the filter should be something like `stock__symbol=sym.lower()`. Might be a good idea to add indexes to filter lookup columns.

Comment: Yeah, I already tried that but it still shows the "Sorry this page does not exists"